# Let $a$ and $b$ be integers. Show that if $a \equiv b \pmod{p}$ for every prime $p$, then $a = b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be integers. Show that if $a \equiv b \pmod{p}$ for every prime $p$, then $a = b$.

**My attempt:**

Suppose that $p\mid (a-b)$ and $a-b\neq 0$. Then $p\leq|a-b| $.

Since the set of prime numbers is infinite we can take $p'$ such that $p\leq |a-b|<p'$. But $p'$ divides $a-b$ as well, thus $p'\leq|a-b|$, which is a contradiction. So $a-b=0$, that is, $a=b$. I am right?

Comment: Can't you simply find $p>a,b$, then $a=b$ follows? (Or am i being stupid and missing the obvious)

Comment: @GarethMa Lucas's answer I think explains what I'm trying to say, no?

Comment: Hint: it remains true if you replace the set of primes by any infinite set of integers (so has nothing to do with primes except that there are infinitely many).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\neq b$, there exists a prime which does not divides $a-b$, take $p>|a-b|$, $a-b\neq 0$ mod $p$.

Answer (score 3):

The hypothesis implies that $a-b$ is divisible by every prime. But any nonzero integer is only divisible by finitely many primes. Thus $a-b=0$ and hence $a=b$